# Configure celery to wait for backend service to start

Tags: python, celery

When starting up celery, it retries connecting to my rabbitmq broker, which gives it the necessary time to load. This is good, because I'm using docker and I can't guarantee the order in which services start and precisely which service will be up when.

However, while trying to connect to the local mysql server I set up as the results backend, celery does not use the same measure of mercy and dies instantly, complaining, reasonably, that it can't lock the mysqld socket:

```
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I would like to configure celery to retry several times before giving up, is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

celery use sqlalchemy behind the scene, it does not ship with connect retry feature out of the box, however, you could adjust the connect timeout, to wait longer for mysql server, by default this value is only 10s, larger value helps.

assuming you are using pymysql/mysqldb as DB driver, it accepts a [`connect_timeout`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html) option, to specify this option from celery, you need set [`database_engine_options`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-engine-options), which will be [passed to](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/database/__init__.py#L79-L81) the [`create_engine`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/database/session.py#L39) function of sqlalchemy, and set [`connect_args`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.connect_args), which will be passed directly from sqlalchemy to DB driver, eg:

```
app.conf.database_engine_options = {'connect_args': {'connect_timeout': 600}}
```

another option is to use a custom connection [`creator`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#using-a-custom-connection-function) function, manage the connection creation all by yourself, you could retry whatever times you want.

Comment: Using MySQLdb if you're referring to the library

Comment: mysqldb supports connect_timeout option as well.

Comment: Thanks. I no longer need this (and I don't really remember how I solved it) but your answer is appreciated and accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `depends_on` option in docker-compose. It defines the order in which the services you want start. You can find the [official documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Comment: I'm using it. It guarantees the order in which docker machines are loaded, but it does not guarantee the services in those docker machines are up and running.

Comment: Can you do an example with MySQL like the question specified?